# Linking SQL query to UserForm ComboBox, data can't be picked

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking online for example of codes to populate a ComboBox in UserForm (Excel) with data from SQL query and came across this:

```
Private Sub DieSearch_DropButtonClick()

'Declare Variables
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stDB As String, stConn As String, stSQL As String

'Set database connection string. This connects excel with SQL database
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

    stConn = "driver={SQL Server};server=server;database=SQL;uid=ID;pwd=ABCD"

With cnt
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .ConnectionString = stConn
    .Open
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

'SQL Query statement
    stSQL = " select distinct [inv] from [SQL].[dbo].[ENTRY] order by [Inv]"

    rst.Open stSQL, cnt
    DieSearch.Clear

Do While Not rst.EOF
    DieSearch.AddItem rst(0)
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

'Release objects from memory.
rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
cnt.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is my code which I changed login string and SQL query. When testing, I found out that although the ComboBox can show the data, I cannot choose any of them. I can still type in the box, but I can't pick from the list.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the handler invoked? FWIW unless you need to involve parameters, you should run that query and populate the combobox only once when the form is activated, instead of everytime the dropbutton is clicked.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of putting the code in `Userform_Initialize`...

Comment: Keep in mind that the `Initialize` handler runs before the `foo` reference is set in `Set foo = New MyForm` - you'd have to be ok with that statement having the side-effect of hitting a database ;-)